# why is count(*) vs select using an index key of different performances?

Tags: mysql

Why would these two queries be of different performances?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE indexKey = someValue;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE indexKey = someValue;
```

They are both using an index key to do the select operation. Other than the actual data being returned (a single number vs rows of data), is there any other reason `COUNT` is more optimized?

Comment: If they're using the same index, the performance should be the same except for transmitting the data.

Comment: "Other than the actual data being returned (a single number vs rows of data)"  - that's actually quite a difference, possibly involving quite different processing steps, depending on the actual query and the table layout. An `EXPLAIN` query might be able to clear things up. If that's not enough, we would need a lot more details for an actual non-handwavey answer.

Comment: The `SELECT COUNT(*)` query will only need to read from the index, whereas the `SELECT *` will need to read the table data (clustered index) for each row to be returned.

Comment: Is `someValue` meant to be an actual value, or a column in the table?

Comment: `COUNT(1)` is more optimized for not having to sub query the internal `columns` table

Comment: @ITgoldman [_"InnoDB handles SELECT COUNT(*) and SELECT COUNT(1) operations in the same way. There is no performance difference."_](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count:~:text=InnoDB%20handles%20SELECT%20COUNT(*)%20and%20SELECT%20COUNT(1)%20operations%20in%20the%20same%20way.%20There%20is%20no%20performance%20difference.)

Comment: @Barmar - There are more slowdowns -- it must use the PK to find the row and fetch the columns.  Furthermore, if any columns are bulky `TEXT`, it must go "off-record", which is potentially an extra disk read.

Comment: @RickJames I meant that to be part of "transmitting the data". I thought it was obvious that reading the data from disk is part of it.

Comment: @user1191247 i suspected there would be some optimization, but i meant that methodically and that one shouldn't rely on optimization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE indexKey = someValue;
```

Will use the B+Tree for `INDEX(indexKey)`, dive into it at `someValue`, scan forward, and stop when no longer seeing `someValue`.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE indexKey = someValue;
```

Will run one of two ways, each is slower than the above `COUNT`.

- Use the B+Tree for `INDEX(indexKey)` as discussed above, but the reach over (via the `PRIMARY KEY`, which is implicitly included in the BTree) to find the rest of the columns (`*`).  That a lot of back-and-forth, and a lot of stuff to send to the client.
- If the number of rows with `"someValue"` is "large" (more than, say, 20% of the table), simply scan the data's B+Tree, handing only the matching rows to the client.  This eliminates the back-and-forth, but at the expense of reading and tossing the rows that are not needed.

The Optimizer cannot accurately predict which approach is faster, so sometimes it picks the wrong approach.

```
... WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE  indexKey = someValue )
```

Uses the index, but stops after it finds the first match or fails to find a match -- very efficient.  [`1` is a convention; it has nothing to do with "first".]

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = someValue
```

Assuming `id` is the "clustered" `PRIMARY KEY`. it will optimally reach for the one (or zero) row.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE id = someValue
```

Assuming `id` is the "clustered" `PRIMARY KEY`. it will optimally return 0 or 1.  (It is a rather strange formulation.)

Summary:

- `SELECT *` is slower to process (regardless of which way it picks);
- Shoveling the desired rows to the client is slower than simply slowing a single number (the `COUNT`).

A note about count(...) --

- `COUNT(*)` is preferred.  The `*` does not need to look at the columns.
- `COUNT(1)` performs no differently.
- `COUNT(x)` *does* look at `x` -- If `x IS NULL`, that row won't be counted.
- `COUNT(DISTINCT x)` will count the number of different values of `x`.